# MongoDB - Negate $elemMatch query

Tags: mongodb

Having this collection of documents called accommodations...

```
[{
    name: String,
    bookings: [{
        from: Date
        to: Date
        status: String //'CONFIRMED', 'ON_REQUEST', 'PAID'
    }]
}]
```

I want to find all accommodations that doesn't have any booking between the giving dates with the exception of those bookings that have 'ON_REQUEST'.

```
var searchFrom = new Date(2015, 02, 02);
var searchTo = new Date(2015, 02, 05);

{
    name: 'My awesome accommodation',
    bookings: [
    {
      from: Date(2015, 02, 01),
      to: Date(2015, 02, 03),
      status: 'CONFIRMED',
    }, {
      from: Date(2015, 02, 04),
      to: Date(2015, 02, 07),
      status: 'ON_REQUEST'
    }, {
      from: Date(2015, 02, 08),
      to: Date(2015, 02, 10),
      status: 'PAID'
    }]
}
```

I'm trying this but $elemMatch condition doesn't discard not allowed bookings and if i negate the $elemMatch it keeps giving me results because both $elemMatch will always match results.

```
db.accommodations.find({
    'bookings': {
        $and: [{
            $elemMatch: {
                'from': {$lte: searchTo},
                'to': {$gte: searchFrom},
                'status': 'ON_REQUEST'
            }
        }, {
            $not: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    'from': {$lte: searchTo},
                    'to': {$gte: searchFrom},
                    'status': {$in: ['CONFIRMED', 'PAID']
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

I wonder how can i solve this with one query and avoid to dev some logic before the query.

Edit: @karthick.k

In this case, the expected result should be empty, because there are bookings in the giving dates, so, i shouldnt be able to book.

If the only existing booking were the 'ON_REQUEST' booking, the expected result should be that accommodation. This means that in the booking dates the user should be able to ask for booking the accommodation (probably under some conditions that both parts should agree).

Comment: Why you checked for `$not` if you only want to find out `status:ON_REQUEST` of given date range, then why you should use `$not` ?

Comment: Post the expected result that wound be helpful

Comment: @yogesh with just the `$elemMatch` for `status:ON_REQUEST` keeps giving a false positive because i'm not checking if exists other bookings in the search dates that has the rest of posible states. The accommodation should not be returned if there are bookings with the exception of `status:ON_REQUEST`.

Comment: @YagoQuinoy Why can't you change the design, I feel its a bad design becoz, Probably you have to embedded another array inside bookings array. Please think about this scenario suppose you need to add user information of CONFIRMED booking , it consist of name, place, multiple address, phone numbers(array), etc. So updating nested array is tedious

Comment: @YagoQuinoy couldn't you just get rid of the whole `$elemMatch` for `status: ON_REQUEST`?

Answer (score 0):

As @karthick.k suggested, i changed the design allowing 'Bookings' to have his own collection and reference them from an accommodation.

So, at the end, to know if an accommodation is available i had to get all accommodation first, get their ids and then obtain all bookings that fulfills the search criteria and perform some logic.

It's sad that i couldn't achieve with just one query but it's true that the booking sub-document would grow a lot and having it inside accommodation would be a pain.